# Soma direto por query SQL

Tags: mysql, query

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer uma soma simples direto pela query, eu tenho uma tabela que contem uma sub-tabela denominada VIEWS e gostaria que a cada query que eu executasse esses VIEWS aumentassem +1 sem eu precisar exercitar muito o PHP, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supondo que a tabela tenha um campo chamado `contador` e este seja incrementado:

```
UPDATE minhatabela SET contador = contador + 1 WHERE pagina = (id da pagina desejada)
```

(O Where está aí também para fins de exemplo. Para mais detalhes, edite a pergunta e acrescente os detalhes que precisar).

Comment: +1 por ter entendido a pergunta.